# Creating Google Scholar Account with professional email

Tags: google-scholar

When I was trying to create google scholar profile, it requires an institutional email. As I no longer have any access to my academic email , I would like to use my professional email , which is provided by my company I am currently working for.

Will it create any problem in future for receiving citations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I don't think you need institutional email to create google scholar profile. you can use your gmail to create one. You may need institutional email to verify your profile to show you are affiliated with the verified institution.

It may not create problem receiving future citation because citation receiving depends upon people citing your research work. You can still list all of your published article under one account and google scholar will gradually accumulate your citation under your profile once it starts recognizing the article. So, it should not be a problem.